# Vanilla javascript form validations, how to undo prevent default on submit

Tags: javascript

I've tried so many different things that I eventually gave up and switched to jQuery, but for my peace of mind, how would I undo the eventHandler in this case? The current method I have now isn't working.

```
Front end New Profile Form Validations
var profileForm = document.forms[0];

profileForm.onsubmit = function processForm(eventHandler) {
eventHandler.preventDefault();
if {blah blah blah, my code
}else{
  profileForm.submit(function(eventHandler) {
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Comment: Vanilla means no libraries like jQuery. If you want to undo `preventDefault()`, why not just remove that line?

Comment: One good thing to do would probably be to stop using the `.onsubmit` style of event attachment and use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).  Then you could use its companion `removeEventListener()`.  Otherwise you can just `null` the `.onsubmit`

Answer (score 2):

Either null the `.onsubmit` property of your form, or use [`.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

```js
var form = document.getElementById("my-form"),
  button = document.getElementById("my-button"),
  text = document.getElementById("my-text");

function submitHandler(submitEvent) {
  alert("Stopping with value: " + text.value);
  submitEvent.preventDefault();
}

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  form.removeEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
});
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" id="my-text" name="my-text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I love Vanilla xD !